# Unsure of how to fix this error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

So I'm creating my first ever program in Python and I've got it all made up into tiny parts and I'm having trouble putting it all together.

The code that I've extracted for this post is basically logging in, using a premade .txt called "*yournamehere* profile.txt" where the first 2 lines have your username and password which is checked and lets you log in.

Then I have it so you can go and enter in your details, however I'm getting an error: TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str', which after looking up I'm assuming is caused by the file not being open in the correct part of code.

I'm sorry if my code is messy or badly done, it's my first ever program so if you have any tips or ways to make it nicer I'll appreciate those too :P

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="#CCFFCC")

#========--------------PERSONAL DETAILS START-------------==========#
def Personal():
    Personal=Toplevel(root)
    Personal.title("Personal Details")
    Personal.configure(bg="#CCFFCC")
    #----COMMANDS W/ WIDGETS----#
    #First Name
    def WriteFName():
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("First Name: ")
        file.write(str(entryFName.get()))
        file.write("\n")
        labelSaveFName.configure(text="Saved")
    labelFName = Label(Personal, text="First name: ", bg="#ccffcc")
    entryFName = Entry(Personal)
    buttonFName = Button(Personal, text="Save", command=WriteFName, bg="#93FF00")
    labelSaveFName = Label(Personal, text="...", bg="#ccffcc")
    #Last Name
    def WriteLName():
        file.write("Last Name: ")
        file.write(str(entryLName.get()))
        file.write("\n")
        labelSaveLName.configure(text="Saved")
    labelLName = Label(Personal, text="Last name: ", bg="#ccffcc")
    entryLName = Entry(Personal)
    buttonLName = Button(Personal, text="Save", command=WriteLName, bg="#93FF00")
    labelSaveLName = Label(Personal, text="...", bg="#ccffcc")
    #Age
    def WriteAge():
        file.write("Age: ")
        file.write(str(entryAge.get()))
        file.write("\n")
        labelSaveAge.configure(text="Saved")
    labelAge = Label(Personal, text="Age: ", bg="#ccffcc")
    entryAge = Entry(Personal)
    buttonAge = Button(Personal, text="Save", command=WriteAge, bg="#93FF00")
    labelSaveAge = Label(Personal, text="...", bg="#ccffcc")
    #----GRID----#
    labelFName.grid(row=0, column=0)
    entryFName.grid(row=0, column=1)
    buttonFName.grid(row=0, column=2)
    labelSaveFName.grid(row=0,column=3)
    labelLName.grid(row=1, column=0)
    entryLName.grid(row=1, column=1)
    buttonLName.grid(row=1, column=2)
    labelSaveLName.grid(row=1, column=3)
    labelAge.grid(row=2, column=0)
    entryAge.grid(row=2, column=1)
    buttonAge.grid(row=2, column=2)
    labelSaveAge.grid(row=2, column=3)

#=================--------PERSONAL DETAILS END-------================#

#=====----CHOOSING WHAT TO INPUT START----=====#
def details():
    detailswindow=Toplevel(root)
    detailswindow.configure(bg="#CCFFCC")
    detailswindow.title("Choose")
    def end():
        detailswindow.destroy()
    #---WIDGETS---#
    PersonalButton = Button(detailswindow, text="Personal Details", command=Personal, bg="#93ff00")
    CloseButton = Button(detailswindow, text="Close Window", command=end, bg="#93ff00")
    #---GRID---#
    PersonalButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
    CloseButton.grid(row=1, column=1)
#=====----CHOOSING WHAT TO INPUT END----=====#

#======----LOG-IN WINDOW START----======#
def newwindow():
    login=Toplevel(root)
    login.configure(bg="#CCFFCC")
    name=raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
    file = open(name.lower() + " profile.txt", "a+")
    #---Commands---#
    def end():
        login.destroy()
    def callback():
        line = file.readlines()
        username = user.get()
        password = passw.get()
        if username == line[0].strip() and password == line[1].strip():
            Message.configure(text = "Logged in.")
            proceed.configure(text="Proceed", command=details)
        else:
            Message.configure(text = "Username and password don't match the account \n under the name;\n \'" + name + "\'. \nPlease try again.")
        return f
    #---LOG-IN WIDGETS---#
    #labels
    LogInTitle = Label(login, text="Please log in.", bg="#CCFFCC").grid(row=0, column=1)
    UserTitle = Label(login, text="Username:", bg="#CCFFCC").grid(row=1, column=0)
    PassTitle = Label(login, text="Password:", bg="#CCFFCC").grid(row=2, column=0)
    Message = Label(login, bg="#CCFFCC")

    #text entry windows
    user = Entry(login)
    passw = Entry(login, show='*')

    #buttons
    go = Button(login, text="Log in!", command = callback, bg="#93ff00").grid(row=3, column=1)
    proceed = Button(login, text="...", bg="#93ff00")
    close = Button(login, text="Close window", command=end, bg="#93FF00")
    #===--LOG-IN GRID===--#
    user.grid(row=1, column=1)
    passw.grid(row=2, column=1)
    Message.grid(row=4, column=1)
    proceed.grid(row=5, column=1)
    close.grid(row=5, column=0)
#=====----LOG-IN WINDOW END----=====#

#====----OPENING PAGE----=====#
def destroyroot():
    root.destroy()
LogInButton = Button(root, text="Log In", bg="#93ff00", command=newwindow).grid(row=1, column=0)
CloseRoot = Button(root, text="Close window", bg="#93ff00", command=destroyroot).grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
#===--OPENING PAGE END---====#

#======================-------------END------------------======================#
```

Comment: Break this down into smaller pieces. Not only will this encourage other people to help find your error, it will probably lead to you finding the problem yourself. You should also read the traceback because it probably tells you what line the error comes from.

Comment: Just quickly coping and pasting this into an editor reveals an error on line #92, `return f`. `f` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. However I don't think that's causing your error. Please post a full traceback as it'll be easier to diagnose exactly where the error is occuring.

Comment: Oops sorry yeah, I was meant to remove the return f bit, I was just playing with it to see if I could remove the error using that. This is the traceback I'm getting:    `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "file path", line 14, in WriteFName
    file.write("\n")
TypeError: descriptor 'write' requires a 'file' object but received a 'str'`

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting correctly the `file` variable. You define it in a function, `newwindow`, however that variable is not being set in other functions. Also, `file` is a type in python (such as `int`, `list`, etc...). So you should NOT be using it as a name, it is where the error comes from. You are doing `file.write` so it's getting the `write` from the type, not the variable, and you are getting extraneous errors.

Comment: Alright, so I've changed all of the `file` to `f` for the mean time, could you provide and example of how I could correctly set the variable using something similar to what I have?

I'm just struggling to picture how it should look and I feel an example would really help me.

Cheers.

Comment: You should pass it as a parameter to the functions. I can't provide an example, as your code is rather extensive, but if you have troubles with it I recommend playing with simpler code before doing this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

Some Python basics for you:

1) "from Tkinter import *" is bad form.  It gets real messy when you "import *" from several modules.  Try "import Tkinter" instead.  Reference methods as "Tkinter.xxxx". Like for example "personal = Tkinter.Toplevel(root)".

2) "file" is a type in Python, so you should never ever use it as a variable name.  Using "str" and "len" as variable names are other common gotchas for new Python users.

Moving on, your code seems really complex with all the nested functions.

You might do better with classes if you have groups of variables shared across a different functions.  Here is a very simple example class that also shows the correct way to write to a file:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, file_name = r'c:\myfile.txt'):
        self.file_name = file_name

    def write_to_file(self, stuff_to_write):
        with open(self.file_name, 'a') as f:
            f.write(stuff_to_write)

    def WriteLName(self, name):
        text = "Last Name: %s\n"%name
        self.write_to_file(text)

output = MyClass(r'c:\output_file.txt')
output.WriteLName('Jones')
```

Makes a file called c:\output_file.txt with the text "Last Name: Jones" in it.

When you define a variable within a function, it is not automatically "global", so other functions do not see it:

```
def open_file():
    fout = open(r'c:\myfile.txt', 'w') 
def write_file():
    fout.write('some text\n')

open_file()
write_file()
```

Gives this error when you hit the "fout.write" line:

```
NameError: global name 'fout' is not defined
```

If you add global declarations, it works as you expect.  Many would say that this is "bad form" but as a quick fix for your existing code, it might be something to try.

```
def open_file():
    global fout
    fout = open(r'c:\myfile.txt', 'w') 
def write_file():
    global fout
    fout.write('some text\n')
open_file()
write_file()
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply, I'm heading off for bed now but I'll be sure to have a play with the things you've mentioned tomorrow!

Comment: As an addition to 1), you can use `import Tkinter as tk` if you don't want to write out Tkinter every time. This way you can use `tk.xxx` instead of `Tkinter.xxx`